# Expose an OnClick event in a custom template button , in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, onclick

In Blend,  I took a simple button --> Edit Template --> Create Empty...
Added an image for the button, and filled some visual states.

Now I want to expose an OnClick event :

```
public partial class MyButton : UserControl
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();          
        button.Click += Click;                                          
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click;
}
```

But this doesn't work for me. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly doesn't work here, but looks like you're trying to assign `Click` delegate to your `button.Click` event while `Click` is empty. What you should do is assign another delegate which will invoke `Click`.

Replace `button.Click += Click;` with:

```
button.Click += (sender, args) => { if (Click != null) Click(sender, args); };
```